# Google play APK upload error Duplicate declarations of permission

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have tried to upload new apk (signed with my own relese key store), and got follwing error in google play developer console.

> Duplicate declarations of permission
>   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION with different
>   maxSdkVersions.

However previously I was able to upload APK fine without any error, I did not do eny change releted to permissions, so this is strange issue, I have searched on google and could not find workable solution. Is this because of new update on google play developer console ?

Manifest permission declarations
[image]

Gradle dependancies

```
compile 'com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Merged manifest
[image]

Comment: Some of your library must be using the permission that you app does not use. Have your declared this permission in your app `manifest.xml`?

Comment: Which is the value of your `maxSdkVersions` in this permission?

Comment: @MatPag I have not declared maxSdkVersions in the manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Probably you are using a third party library that declare ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION for api level equal or greater than 23. In order to solve this problem you can split the permission in manifest. Just replace this line with your existing uses permission line:

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
  android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

Warning: Be careful that if the third-party library change/remove this permission, your app won't work for api level 23 and higher. So you should check your apk before upload to make sure it works fine

Comment: Ya make sense, let me try

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a not explicit permission added by one of the dependencies of your project during Manifest merging.

You could try updating all the GMS libraries to the latest version and see if the problem disappear. They had a lot of problems with wronged merged permissions [(see release notes)](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), the last one solved with 10.0.1 release

Comment: Tried this if I add this it will effect to the location update of the app

Comment: Can you add the dependencies of your app?

Comment: @DineshAnuruddha i've checked your updated question, obviously GPS add some permissions automatically in your Manifest. What i suggest you is analyzing the final APK manifest using the function *Build -> Analyze APK...* and then open the merged Manifest and see what's there and check for duplicated permissions

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just checkd please ref updated question, It says <uses-permission-sdk-23
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> I think this is the problem, Any idea

Comment: which is your targetSdkVersion? Do you have implemented runtime permissions?

Comment: target sdk 25 and yes implemented runtime permission

Comment: Mmm i'm starting to suspect a bug in one of the GCM libraries which add permission which they shouldn't add, If you read [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) you will see they had a lot of problems with merged permissions (last one resolved in 10.0.1). Could you try updating all your GPS dependencies to the latest version 10.2.6 then build and analyze the manifest APK again?