# Debugging the result of MSBUILD AndroidManifest merge

Tags: android, xamarin.android, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

- VS 2022 17.1.0
- Xamarin Android SDK 12.2.0.4

We have a Xamarin Forms project that includes an Android target. That Android target has recently been updated to have a targetSdkVersion 31 (Android 12)

We are now getting the following errors when trying to upload our Signed APK to Google Play

> Duplicate declarations of permission
> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION with different
> maxSdkVersions. Duplicate declarations of permission
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with different maxSdkVersions.

If I look at the signed APK created by VS2022 build I can see these entries in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

How can I see what is causing these permission values to be merged into our AndroidManifest?

Our currently released build has a targetSdkVersion of 30 (Android 11) and whilst these duplicate permissions are present in the merged manifest for that relesase, Google Play does not complain.

Other AndroidManifest values that might be important are

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="3.7.0"
    android:installLocation="0"
    android:compileSdkVersion="31"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="12"
    package="com.OurCompany.OurApp"
    platformBuildVersionCode="31"
    platformBuildVersionName="12">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="24"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />


OTHER VALUES REMOVED

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Had you tried to remove the repetition of the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml when you set the android:targetSdkVersion="31"?

Comment: No but that's becauise I didn't put it there in the first place. They are being added by something during the build process and I cannot tell what. I'm assuming any removal would be pointless as by that point the APK has been signed

Comment: The cause may be the packages you added in your project declared the permission, you can check [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490337/play-store-publish-error-how-to-validate) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299197/google-play-apk-upload-error-duplicate-declarations-of-permission).

Comment: Is there a way if finding out what libraries are adding what permissions?

Comment: You can try to remove the declarations of the repeated permission added by yourself, just let the package declare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to trace which component was adding ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission entries.

The only way I found to track it down was from all the entries in the "obj" folder under "lp" e.g. \obj\Debug\120\lp

This was wear the various libraries I was using would unpack themselves. I search that folder for occurences of "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" and that gave me the library name that was the problem

The change I made in our AndroidManifest was

<uses-permission-sdk-23
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
tools:node="remove"
android:maxSdkVersion="30" /

Note the use of the tools:node attribute, the Android docs for this are here, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests